# I have a problem i can't put a paragraph above the video i put in the background

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a problem i can't put a paragraph above the video i put in the background,when i write something it goes up to the navbar please help

Can be able to write above an video in html and css

Comment: The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO,  but I'm afraid there is absolutely no way anyone can help you seeriously without seeing your HTML structure and existing relevant CSS - any answer you receive at the moment will just be a wild guess. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.